# How omit struct filed

Tags: go, go-echo

How can I omit struct filed, in my case I login user and return response with user data and token but in this case I need to remove password field, how can I do this ?

```golang
type LoginFormData struct {
    Login    string `json:"name"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
}

data := new(LoginFormData)

if err := c.Bind(data); err != nil {
    return err
}

userData := data // omit password field

        return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, map[string]interface{}{
            "user": struct {
                Password string `json:"-"`
                *LoginFormData
            }{
                LoginFormData: userData,
                Password:      userData.Password,
            },
            "token": "slkdfj",
        })
```

Comment: Use `json:"-"` for the password field?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add new struct than describe desired struct

```golang
type LoginFormResponse struct {
    Login    string `json:"name"`
    Password string `json:"-"`
}
```

2. Convert

```golang
return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, map[string]interface{}{
            "user":  LoginFormResponse(*data),
            "token": "slkdfj",
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a helper package to handle api response

for example:
helper/response_formatter.go:

```golang
package helper

type Response struct {
    Message string `json:"message"`
    Data interface{} `json:"data"`
}

func ResponseFormatter(message string, data interface{}) Response {
    response := Response{
        Message: message
        Data: data,
    }

    return response
}
```

then in echo handler:

```golang
response := helper.ResponseFormatter("authenticated", userData)

return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, response)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to resolve the problem in the wrong way.

The best practice when constructing an API is to have 2 structs for this. One for the request fields, one for the response fields. Like this:

```
type LoginFormReq struct {
    Login    string `json:"name"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
}

type LoginFormResp struct {
    Login    string `json:"name"`
    Password string `json:"-"`
}
```

This can sometimes lead to a lot of copying of data between structs, but that is kinda normal on Go development with proper separation of concerns. I usually use https://github.com/jinzhu/copier to handle this. It's a great library!